# Getting Log file does not exist: when trying to run a dag on airflow locally

Tags: python, ubuntu, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am running airflow locally on my ubuntu machine, my airflow.cfg file is in the directory: `/home/airflow/airflow` so I created a subdirectory for my dags i.e `/home/airflow/airflow/dags/` and created a dag there.

The dag I created to check sample output is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
}


with DAG(
    dag_id='our_first_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='This is our first dag that we write',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 7, 29, 2),
    schedule_interval='@daily'
) as dag:
    task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='first_task',
        bash_command="echo hello world, this is the first task!"
    )

    task1
```

I then ran `airflow dags list` to check if it was detected, i got the following output:

```
$ airflow dags list
dag_id           | filepath         | owner   | paused
=================+==================+=========+=======
our_first_dag    | our_first_dag.py | airflow | False
```

But when I restart my airflow scheduler and webserver, and run the dag, I get this error as my output:

```
*** Log file does not exist: /home/airflow/airflow/logs/dag_id=our_first_dag_v5/run_id=manual__2022-11-13T01:35:03.807018+00:00/task_id=first_task/attempt=4.log
*** Fetching from: http://:8793/log/dag_id=our_first_dag_v5/run_id=manual__2022-11-13T01:35:03.807018+00:00/task_id=first_task/attempt=4.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.
```

The directory contents are:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 airflow airflow  50564 Nov 12 12:56 airflow.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 airflow airflow 454656 Nov 11 13:07 airflow.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 airflow airflow      7 Nov 12 18:12 airflow-webserver.pid
drwxrwxr-x 3 airflow airflow   4096 Nov 12 18:08 dags
drwxrwxr-x 4 airflow airflow   4096 Nov 12 17:56 logs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 airflow airflow   4743 Nov 11 12:57 webserver_config.py
```

I don't have `docker-compose.yaml` file in my airflow.

Any help would be appreciated thanks! I am not sure why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the executor in `airflow.cfg` from `CeleryExecutor` to `SequentialExecutor`, and it worked for me. I'm not sure why celery executor isn't working, it is not ideal by any means but atleast the dags are now running.